# HoloLens emulator connect to server on LAN

Tags: networking, lan, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have a websocket server running on a pc connected to the pc through a switch.
When I make a websocket client in the HoloLens with the IP of the server it doesn't connect. How come? I cannot ping the HoloLens emulator from the pc with the server but I can ping the pc running the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all interactions with the emulator are done through a 169.254.xxx.xxx address.  This address is not externally routable.  If you go to the networking menu option in the web portal for the emulator you should see two network adapters, one is the 169.254.xxx.xxx address and another is an address assigned via dhcp.  My guess is that you don't have a second adapter and need to fix that in your Hyper V configuration for the emulator.  If you do have that second adapter pinging that address will not work, because HoloLens does not run and ICMP server to respond to pings.  A better test is to open Internet Explorer in the emulator and attempt to go to a valid web server address on your network.  Here is what my settings look like as an example:

[image]