# Why TCP connection doesn't work in HoloLens emulator (1st generation)?

Tags: c#, windows, hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

I searched the entire Internet looking for information, but it did not help. The main problem: **I can’t connect from the HoloLens emulator to my server.**

### How my code works:

I am starting the server. He is waiting for connections. When a client connects to the server, it sends a message. In this case, this is "This is a message from one of your clients." [image: server_1]

[image: server_2]

### What is at the moment:

1. The server that opens at the IP that recommended in [this article.](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/309/emulator-and-localhost)

   ```
   System.Net.IPAddress ipAddr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.37.97");
   IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);
   Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   ```
2. I took the IPs from **cmd** where I wrote 'ipconfig'.[image: ipconfig]
3. If we talk about the parameters of the HoloLens emulator, then here it is. [image: HololensIP]

---

You can see that the ip addresses are different in the emulator and in 'ipconfig'. Let's try to put the emulator ip in the server address (just in case we will check).[image: exeption]

As you can see, an error appears. `"The requested address is not valid in its context"`.

## And what do I want?

If there is any exact step-by-step instruction on how to connect from the emulator to my server, I will be very grateful.

Below I will leave links that have helped many, but not me. (Maybe because I'm a junior)

*Links:*

1) https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/309/emulator-and-localhost

2) https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/comment/934/#Comment_934

3) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets (**Note:** As a consequence of network isolation, Windows disallows establishing a socket connection...)

4) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/

5) [HoloLens emulator connect to server on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763534/hololens-emulator-connect-to-server-on-lan)

Comment: This is because your HoloLens is not on the same network (IP range wise) as your computer. Your `ipconfig` screenshot shows us that the adapter to the HoloLens has the IP `10.10.2.106`. So instead of connecting to `192.168.37.97` try `var ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.2.106");`

Comment: Yes, I changed the ip address. But the HoloLens emulator does not see the server at this address(

Answer (score 0):

The HoloLens Emulator can connect to a server on your host PC (or any other device reachable on the network to which your host PC is attached) as long as the server is listening on the host's IP, not the emulator IP, and your host firewall is configured to allow inbound connectivity on the port you choose.  For example, if your host is 10.0.0.1, your emulator is 192.168.0.1 and you want to use port 8080, the server should be listening on 10.0.0.1:8080, the firewall should be configured to allow inbound connections on port 8080 and the client should connect to that address and port.